# Zero of a function $f(x)=E[|Z+x|^k(Z^2-1)]$ where $Z$ is standard normal.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

Let 
\begin{align}
f(x)=E[|Z+x|^k(Z^2-1)] 
\end{align}

I have observed the following behavior of f(x)

> For $k \in (0,1)$   there exists an $x_0$ sucht that $f(x)$ changes
>   sign at $x=x_0$.

In other words, $f(x)$ has a zero for some $x_0$.

Note that 
\begin{align}
f(0)=E[|Z|^{k+2}] -E[|Z|^k] \ge 0
\end{align}

So, by continuity suffice to show that there exists an $x_0$ such that $f(x)<0$.

Comment: You should be able to show that $f(x)$ is negative for all $x$ sufficiently large $x$ by using the standard asymptotic expansions for the confluent hypergeometric function.  Your $f$ is essentially the second derivative of ${}_1F_1(-k/2,1/2;-x^2/2)$, and the differential equation $zw''+(b-z)w'-aw=0$ (after paying due regard to the chain rule) allows you to write $f$ as a linear combination of two ${}_1F_1$ functions, with well known asymptotics.  I *think* for large $x$, the function $f$ converges to $0$ from below.

Comment: You should be able to derive an asymptotic expansion for $f(x)$ valid for large $x$ by replacing $|Z+x|^k$ with the even terms in the binomial expansion for $x^k|1+Z/x|^k$, namely, $x^k(1+\binom{k}{2}Z^2/t^2+\ldots)$. When you integrate this against $Z^2-1$ the constant term vanishes and you are left with $x^{k-2} E(Z^4-Z^2)\binom{k}{2}+\dots$, which is negative for large $x$. (The odd terms vanish when integrated against $(Z^2-1)$.)

Comment: @kimchilover But this would work only for integer $k$, right?

Comment: I meant, Newton's generalized [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).  You still have work to do (to show that the remainder is $o(x^{k-2})$).